# How to make custom citation style (author, year)?

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using Overleaf, the preamble related to my bib is:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

In the document I'd like to call citation in the form of `(Hoek, 2007)`. I've managed to do it, but it's a bit long and annoying to type in text:

```
(\citeauthor{hoek2007}, \citeyear{hoek2007})
```

I'm new to commands, I made an attempt but the Overleaf commands explanation is going over my head. What I tried:

```
\newcommand{\citeay}[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1})}
```

But the result of `\citeay{hoek2007}` is just `[1]`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With your ``\citeay`` command defined this way, there should be no problem and you should get the expected result. Could you post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so we can see where the problem comes from? Working on a minimal example could even help you to solve the problem yourself! :)

Comment: Load `natbib` as `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}` and use `\citep`. You shouldn't have to define something like `\citeay` `natbib` supports author-year citations out of the box. If that doesn't help I suggest you add a full MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to your question that shows exactly what you are doing at the moment.

Comment: As an aside it is weird that `(\citeauthor{hoek2007}, \citeyear{hoek2007})` in the text should work but `\newcommand{\citeay}[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1})}` in the preamble and then `\citeay{hoek2007}` in the document not. They should give exactly the same result. (Unless something redefines `\citeay` later on. But we can only help with that if we see an MWE.)

Comment: Do make sure to load the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear` if you wish to get authoryear-style citation callouts.

Answer (score 1):

> But the result of `\citeay{hoek2007}` is just `[1]`. :-(

You need to load the `natbib` package with the options `authoryear` and `round`:

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round,<other options>]{natbib}
```

> In the document I'd like to [create citation call-outs of] the form of `(Hoek, 2007)`.

No need to create the macro you call `\citeay`. Just use natbib's `\citep` macro (short for "parenthetic-style citation call-out", I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

I was going to type this in a comment but I didn't know how to format comments on StackExchange.

In writing the MWE I found the source of the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{revtex4-1}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
Some words and stuff. \citep{hoek2007}.

\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

When using `\documentclass{article}` `\citep{...}` produces the desired `(Hoek, 2007)`. But when I used `\documentclass{revtex4-1}` for some reason it overrides it (I was using this documentclass because I was using a template). Hence that was, at least one of the things that clashed according to the error message on Overleaf:

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.
```